# Comparing 2 arrays of objects properties, adding property to 1 object

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, comparison

My first question here.
I have a script with 2 arrays of objects where 1 property from object1 match 1 property from object 2. When the properties match, object1 gets a new property based on a property in object2.
The range of properties can be around 5-20 different ones and the array holding object1 can easily contain 100+ objects so if there is a better way to do it other than double loops that would be great, but i am still new to handling/comparing objects in this way.

So far i have this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
foreach ($vm in $vms)
 {
 foreach ($csv in $csvs)
  {
  if ($vm.location -eq $csv.ownerNode)
    {$vm = $vm | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name csv -Value $csv.name}   
  }
 }
```

*edit for more background, also posted further down*
The reason i chose to use objects is that i need to add more and more properties as the scrip runs, then at the end use them (around 4-5 properties per object) to sort them and then do different actions based on the different properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only properties you need from the objects in `$csvs` are the `OwnerNode` and then `Name` properties, you might speed up the process (and limit the memory footprint) by creating a `hashtable` that use the `OwnerNode` as its Key and the `Name` as its value (assuming that both properties are of type `string`):

```
$CsvLookup = @{}

$csvs |Foreach-Object {
    $CsvLookup[$_.OwnerNode] = $_.Name
}

# No need for this anymore
Remove-Variable csvs

foreach($vm in $vms){
    if($CsvLookup.ContainsKey($VM.Location)){
        $vm = $vm |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CSV -Value $CsvLookup[$VM.Location] -PassThru
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a good solution, sadly i need the object with the added property intact (object1/vm) for processing later in the script.
The reason i chose to use objects is that i need to add more and more properties as the scrip runs, then at the end use them (around 4-5 properties per object to sort them and then do different actions based on the different properties).

Comment: @Jack_W not sure I follow? You could change the hashtable to use the entire object as its value if that's the case, ie. `$CsvLookup[$_.OwnerNode] = $_`

Comment: Oh, right, i didn't read you example properly. Yes that should work just fine, thank you! :)